# Function name changes (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, properties

I am working on a script and everythink worked fine, until a few days ago. I have an object, created with `function()`, where I work with several methods. 
To access properties inside the object, I use the `this` keyword and that works fine.
As example:

```
var SeralCore = SeralCore || function () 
{
    this.initSeral();
    return this;
};

SeralCore.prototype = {
     page = null;

     initSeral = function ()
     {
          alert(this.page);
     }
}
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/81Zn9276
jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/g2ahu6ob/10/

When I have an event, where a callback is fired and I have to access the property `page`, I used the following, because I can't use `this` anymore:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
     SeralCore.page = 'Some value';
});
```

This worked well, but suddenly there is an error saying I cannot reach an property (or object, in my case*) used like in the exameple above. The output is `undefined`.

I decided to investigate what the output would be if I log `SeralCore`. Surprisingly, it says the following:
[image: Ouput when logging <code>SeralCore</code>]

As you can see, there is a `<` at the end of SeralCore, which doesn't belong there.
Is this normal? And is this the cause of not being able to access properties using the "full name" (`SeralCore.page`)? If so, is there a way to fix it?

Many, many thanks in advance because I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Snippet:

```js
var SeralCore = SeralCore || function () {
        this.initSeral();
        return this;
    };

window.onload = function () {
    this.SeralCore = new SeralCore();
};

SeralCore.prototype = {

    page: 'Page',
    
    initSeral: function ()
    {
        this.registerPage.start();
    },
    
    registerPage: {
        start: function ()
        {
            $('.output').text(typeof SeralCore.page + ' (Should show \'String\' when it can read SeralCore.page)');
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="output"></span>
```

Comment: Are you testing this in a browser? If so, which one, and does it occur in others?

Comment: Your code isn't even valid and wouldn't run at all. Post your *actual* code.

Comment: Your `prototype` will not run.

Comment: Good point. Tested it in Firefox only. Chrome ouputs it correctly. So the only problem the property which I can't read. And added the full code. Prototype is running, while other functionalities do work.

Comment: create a demo instead of using pasteBin's

Comment: added jsFiddle example.

Comment: The code should be placed directly in the question itself, not just in some other website.

Comment: `SeralCore` doesn't have a `.page` property because `SeralCore` a reference to the local function, not an instance. `this.SeralCore = new SeralCore()` is creating a global variable because `this` is referring to `window`, so it's shadowed by your local `SeralCore` variable/function.